# Wrong line number in Visual Studio Editor - Python source code - after copy/paste source from Visual Studio windows version

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, line-numbers

I have done some programming in Python using Visual Studio in Window.
Now I have just moved some source code from windows to Visual Studio on a Raspberry pi.
Everything seems ok, but when I compile the source I get the wrong line numbers in the editor.
I have used # for comment lines in Windows system, and it works fine.
It seems this is my problem, can I make som setup in Visual Studio on my Raspberry to count these lines ?
Now it seems that the lines are ignored and not counted.

As I'm new to use Raspberry (1 hour), then I think it could be a simple setup issue.

Comment: This could have something to do with the different file endings (Windows vs. Linux).

Comment: Thank You.Yes I know. CR and LF are used in windows and I think only one of them in Linux/Unix. But This setup perhaps could be a option in Visual Studio as well - how to handle line feed ect.